# Is it safe to invoke std::map::erase with std::map::begin?

Tags: c++, dictionary, undefined-behavior, erase

We <sub>(all)</sub> know, erasing an element, pointer by an iterator invalidates the iterator, for example:

```
std::map< .. > map_;
std::map< .. >::iterator iter;
// ..
map_.erase( iter ); // this will invalidate `iter`.
```

But, what about:

```
map_.erase( map_.begin() );
```

is this safe? Will `map_.begin()` be a valid iterator, pointing to the (new) first element of the map?

<sub>"test it" is not a solution.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`begin()` is not an iterator but returns an iterator. After erasing the first element, `begin()`returns another (valid) iterator.

```
 std::map<int, int> m;
 m[1] = 2;
 m[2] = 3;
 m.erase(m.begin()); // <- begin() points to 1:2
 std::cout << m.begin()->second; // <- begin() points to 2:3 now
```

Comment: Aha, seems like this one is what I was (somehow) missing: "begin() is not an iterator but returns an iterator".

Answer (score 3):

On [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase), we see:

> **All iterators (pos, first, last) must be valid and dereferenceable**,
>   that is, the end() iterator (which is valid, but is not
>   dereferencable) cannot be used.

That pretty much answers your question. As long as the iterator **returned** by `begin()` is valid *and* dereferencable, it is OK to be used in `std::map::erase()`. A good way then to check if `begin()` is OK to be used in `std::map::erase` is by checking it if it is not equal to `end()`:

```
if(map.begin() != map.end()) {
   map.erase(map.begin());
}
```

Alternatively, you could also check if the map is empty, and use `std::map::erase` if it isn't

```
if(!map.empty()) {
   map.erase(map.begin());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is.

map::begin returns a **valid** iterator referring to the first element in the map container.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin/

Pay attention to empty map.

Answer (score 1):

> is this safe?

Yes. It invalidates the temporary iterator returned by this call to `begin()`, and that iterator is destroyed at the end of the statement.

> Will `map_.begin()` be a valid iterator, pointing to the (new) first element of the map?

Yes, unless the map is now empty. Erasing an element does not prevent you from creating new iterators to the remaining elements; that would make the map unusable.